# How simply can I populate a string in a list with a GUID value?

Tags: 2010, list

I have a list which contains a number of "Single line of text" types, these can be written with anything the user wants, but should, by default, provide a GUID value.

It seems that one cannot properly create a proper GUID value directly in javascript, so what would be the simplest method for me to automatically populate these fields with a GUID value?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to populate a form instead of providing a default value after an event has occurred you could refer to the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

As it says these methods generally don't provide true GUID values. What I may recommend instead if you need this is to perhaps create a web service that simply returns a newly generated GUID and combine that with some jquery ajax to get the GUID and populate the field in the form.

Comment: Good suggestions, although as you say the first isn't really GUID. 
The web service idea isn't terrible either. But I'm hoping to find a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

The simples way is to create [SPItemEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) and implement [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx), [ItemUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is how to obtain a guid in javascript you can render a JS variable to your page from server-side code and populate it with anything you want. You can create a delegate control ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470880.aspx)'s the step-by-step guide exactly for your task) and do the following:

```
public class MyDelegateControl : WebControl
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            if (!Page.IsCallback && !Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string script = String.Format("var myGuid = '{0}';", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "NewGuidsScript", script, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need 10 guids simply create 10 variables or an array or anything you want.